# Day wise + hour bucketing in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with a timestamp in each record. I need to aggregate the records of the collection per day of the week, and within it, on an hourly basis. I took a look at the aggregation / grouping queries here in SO, but I'm not sure how to use it in my scenario

Collection: Alerts
Docs:

```
{
    isOpen: true,
    Time: // ISO("time_string"),
    ...
    ...
 }
```

I would like the aggs to be similar to how elasticsearch datetime histogram behaves.

Output:

```
{
   day: "sunday",
   time: "12am",
   openAlerts: 23
},
{
   day: "sunday",
   time: "1am",
   openAlerts: 13
},
{
   day: "sunday",
   time: "2am",
   openAlerts: 0
},
```

Special emphasis on the 0 counts in the hour bucket. Is there a way to fill in 0s when there is no doc count?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Would be like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $group: {
         _id: {
            year: { $year: "$Time" },
            month: { $month: "$Time" },
            day: { $dayOfMonth: "$Time" },
            hour: { $hour: "$Time" }
         },
         openAlerts: { $sum: 1 }
      }
   }
])
```